# WAR class access another class from other WAR

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, war, wildfly-8

I a **Jboss Wildfly 8.2** instance I have a webapp `ROOT.war` and another `OTHER.war` and I need that the class `OtherXYZ.class` that is inside `OTHER.war` be able to access `RootXYZ.class`. I've read somewhere that this might be possible using [EAR](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-EARClassLoading) but I don't know how.

### Here there is the schema I need to implement

```
                     ClassesVisibleToAllWars.jar
                     /          |              \    
            (access)/           |(access)       \(access)
                   /            |                \
            Root.war         Other1.war         Other2.war
           /                    |                    |
        R.class              O1.class              O2.class
```

- I **CANNOT** create/use a [Global Module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-HowtoPackageEARsandWARs) to put inside `wildfly/modules` directory. I'll only have access to `standalone/deployments/*` directory
- all classes from `ClassesVisibleToAllWars.jar` must be visible to `R.class`, `O1.class` and `O2.class`, for example
- new other `.war` files might eventually be deployed and this behavior must persist

### Question

Wheare should I put `ClassesVisibleToAllWars.jar` in order to achieve that schema?

Comment: Obviously you are dealing with dependency issue. Why don't you use a build script (Maven/Ant...) to package the dependencies in your .war file? Have you consider **Nexus sonatype**

Comment: Why don't you extract OtherXYZ.class to a jar file OtherXYZ.jar then package the OtherXYZ.jar to both ROOT.war and OTHER.war

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to make a reference to a class in one war from another.

If you deploy as an ear, you could pull RootXYZ.class out of ROOT.war and then place it in a jar that would be on the classpaths of both wars (usually in a /lib directory in the ear). I'm not sure about the exact steps required to set this up in Wildfly, but its' usually a setting in META-INF/application.xml, something like:

```
<library-directory>/lib</library-directory>
```

Since in the above you're already pulling common classes into a jar file, I'd probably just include this jar in each war file as part of my build process.

Comment: "You will not be able to make a reference to a class in one war from another."
Can you provide specification or documentation about this/classes visibility between WARs?

Comment: I can't point to everything except to say that the point of a war file is to contain all the resources needed to run an application.  Ear files used  to package together multiple applications.